# issues with installing, No config files OpenVPN 2.3.2-4.el7.x86_64 on Centos 7

Tags: openvpn, centos7

Having some issues with OpenVPN 2.3.2-4.el7.x86_64 on Centos 7 (it's a VPS with digital ocean).

Basically I am trying to install and configure OpenVPN to use as a VPN server. However it seems I am missing the configuration files this is long winded so if you think you can help details are below and thanks in advance.

#### Here is what I have done thus far:

```
yum install epel-relase
yum install openvpn
yum install openssl openssl-devel
yum install pam-devel
yum install lzo-devel
```

Above commands worked without error and so reading the howto I attempted to start editing the config files so I could learn how OpenVPN works except they don't exist. I see this by running the commands

```
cp /usr/share/doc/openvpn-*/sample-config-files/server.conf /etc/openvpn
```

this throws an error about directories/files that don't exist

Running the below command

```
cd /usr/share/doc/packages/openvpn and cd /usr/share/doc/openvpn
```

I get the following error or some variation of this:

```
bash: /usr/share/doc/packages/openvpn: No such file or directory
```

I'm trying to edit the `server.conf` (with vi/vim) and other related files(that according to the docs and the howto's should be there) gives me a blank file it's almost like I'm not getting the included sample config's

The following google-fu hasn't helped (I did the same searches directly on server fault)

- Openvpn no config files
- how to install openvpn centos 7
- openvpn rpm install vs yum install

I have read some of the manpages for OpenVPN and while useful with examples of config files and options doesn't really specify install issues or directory structures (at least that I can see thus far anyway)

links here:

- openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#config
- community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage

and have read these similar server fault questions here:

- serverfault.com/questions/634676/centos-7-and-openvpn-how-make-them-friends
- serverfault.com/questions/345070/openvpn-incomplete-rpm

I am doubtful that the openvpn doc's are incomplete or wrong but I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong here.

Also finally I did try installing manually via RPM (on a fresh droplet)...but doesn't get me very far
running these commands:

```
wget http://swupdate.openvpn.org/community/releases/openvpn-2.3.2.tar.gz
sudo yum install openssl-devel lzo-devel pam-devel
rpmbuild -tb openvpn-2.3.2.tar.gz
sudo rpm -ivh rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/openvpn-2.3.2-1.x86_64.rpm
```

The final command doesn't work. Basically gives me an error that the folder rpmbuild cannot be found

Sorry for the long winded question...but the TL;DR is that I install openvpn but don't have any config files to work with.

Do I need to wget these files manually to make it work?

Cheers in advance guys and again sorry for the long winded post :)

Comment: Added some formatting to highlight Google searches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try actually looking in the directories to see what was in there, e.g. with `ls`? It looks like you were randomly pasting commands you copied from the Internet without understanding what they do. And it's very concerning that you don't seem to fully understand what `cd` does or how to navigate a directory structure; this is something that you really should learn as soon as possible.

Anyway, I found the sample config files in `/usr/share/doc/openvpn-2.3.2/sample/sample-config-files`, that is, under a further subdirectory. So I suspect you simply never actually looked to see what was there.

Copying the `server.conf` from the correct directory to `/etc/openvpn` appears to work fine. After editing your configuration file to taste, completing the setup is simply `systemctl enable openvpn@server` and `systemctl start openvpn@server`.

Comment: actually yes I do know how to use the cd command in fact to be more specific I found it via doing directory at a time so cd <directory here> then ls to see what I found looking at the howto via the link I posted which shows /usr/share/doc/openvpn once I got to the doc folder and doing an ls there was no openvpn folder to be found I'll check again to make sure but I also did check to make sure there wasn't some version number in the folder name

Comment: to further add I did this one folder at a time to make sure it wasn't some odd typo or something else I was doing :)

Comment: I have no idea how you missed it, then. Have you had enough sleep? :)

Comment: Lol honestly I probably haven't will check back in a moment to see if I find it and if I do find it I will put it down as a herpy derp :P and thank you for your time if not then some more digging will be needed

Comment: ok so checked this again there was no folder with even the name remotely resembling "openvpn" in /usr/share/doc I did a find / -type d -name 'openvpn' the closest I found was /run/openvpn and /etc/openvpn (both of which are expected) I'll run it again from the actual folder to see if i get a different result though that command searches from root...

Comment: Are you sure you installed the right RPM? I have `openvpn-2.3.2-4.el7.x86_64` from EPEL.

Comment: That is what I have if I run (this is probably bad practice but gets the result) 'yum install openvpn' I get 'package openvpn-2.3.2-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version' I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing. By the way I did try the RPM on another droplet but got errors when trying to install it (this is with rpmbuild and gcc) I might try it again (since I have only ever installed an RPM once yonks ago) could the config files be anywhere else?

Comment: If all else fails you can get the [sample configs](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#examples) from OpenVPN's web site.

Comment: yep I think I might do that and just create the directories manually since from my understanding it's all installed just missing several files fingers crossed it works. Also could you point me in the right direction to learn more about building RPM's manually (it seems useful) as there was one thing I noticed and that was yum install openvpn fetched a file of over 1 mb whereas RPM had something like over 10mb that is excluding dependencies :/